# EF Code first issue NO KEY DEFINED

Tags: entity-framework, key, poco, code-first

I am getting following error while using POCO entity width EF

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>     System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Brand' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>     System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Brand' is based
>   on type 'Brand' that has no keys defined.

POCO

```
public class Brand
    {
         //[Key]
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public String BrandName { get; set; }
        public String CompanyName { get; set; }
        public Int32 CountryId { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
    }
```

DBConetxt

```
  public class DBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DBContext()
            : base("DBContext")
        { }


        public DbSet<Brand> Brand { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Country { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>().ToTable("dbo.Brand");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().ToTable("dbo.Country");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

DB Table

```
BrandId int
BrandName   varchar
CompanyName varchar
CountryId   int
Description varchar
CreatedBy   int
CreatedDate datetime
ModifiedBy  int
ModifiedDate    datetime
```

uses

```
DBContext o = new DBContext();
return o.Brand.ToList();
```

If [Key] annotation is used with POCO to indicate pk then it works fine but I don't want to use any dependency class with POCO.

Any suggestions???

Thanks

Comment: Again, Brand has FK property of Country table. While creating New Brand using MVC i need to show list of country as dropdown list. please suggest me best approach to create Brand entity to acheived this scenario?

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using? BrandId should be treated as your key by convention if you are using 4.1+ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh161541(v=vs.103).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the PK using the fluent API. You don't have to explicitly specify the database schema as `dbo`.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>().ToTable("Brand");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>().HasKey(b => b.BrandId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().ToTable("Country");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

You can also define a navigational property `Country` on `Brand` POCO.

```
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public String BrandName { get; set; }
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }
    public Int32 CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country {get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }
}
```

Action method

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["Countries"] = new SelectList(db.Country.ToList(), 
               "CountryId", "CountryName");

        return View();
    }
```

Then in view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, 
          (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Countries"], "-")
```

Comment: Thanks Eranga. Your solution has worked. Eranga, EF do all mapping kind of things dynamically..will it create performance overhead?? can you suggest some performance improvement tips while using EF???

Comment: @Paul The overhead is only one time operation. Your **overhead** is not based on facts. Test whether there is a significant overhead.